# Adding Array elements based on other array

Tags: c#, arrays, sum

I have two arrays whose elements are one to one mapped.

```
string [] denom = new string[]  { EUR, GBP, EUR, USD, USD};

int [] count = new int[]  { 1,  3, 4, 7, 8};

EUR - 1
GBP - 3
EUR - 4
USD - 7
USD - 8
```

I want to get an output into an array by summing the count based on the denom

So, EUR - 5 (1 +4), GBP - 3, USD - 15 (7+8)

**The output array should have values like {5, 3 , 15}**

We have a logic to remap the final count with Denoms (i.e, EUR, GBP, USD)

We want the logic in C#.net

Comment: Can you tag the language that you are using? Looks of it says Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve desired output below code sample will help you.

```
string[] denom = new string[] { "EUR", "GBP", "EUR", "USD", "USD" };
int[] count = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 7, 8 };

//Create dictionary object to manage group by denom
Dictionary<string, int> dct = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//Iterate and sum group by denom
for (int i = 0; i < denom.Length; i++)
{
    if (!dct.Keys.Contains(denom[i]))
        dct[denom[i]] = 0;
    dct[denom[i]] += count[i];
}

//Print output
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kpVal in dct)
    Console.WriteLine(kpVal.Key + "=" + kpVal.Value);
dct.Clear();
```

See the output printed below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a map and keep up the sum as below:

```
Map<String, Integer> currencyValueMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<denom.length; i++) {
    currencyValueMap.put(denom[i], (k, v) v == null ? count[i] : count[i] + v);
}
```

At the end, you would be left with currency name as key while total value as a value against that particular key.

Comment: Thanks for the logic, but I want the logic in C#.Net. I dont see HashMap in C#.Net

Comment: Then you should add that as a tag in question